# Adding a second storyboard causes "could not find storyboard" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I started by building 2 versions of my app, on for 3.5 inch screens and one for 4 inch with only the storyboard being different. I brought the 3.5 storyboard into the 4 inch project and used the following code in my *appDelegate.m* to have the program run the appropriate storyboard.

```
UIViewController *vc;
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
    {
        NSLog(@"IPHONE IS WORKING");
        UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
        vc = [storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainFour.storyboard" bundle:nil];
        vc = [storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
}
else
{
    UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
    vc = [storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
}
[_window setRootViewController:vc];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When I use this, I get the error:

> "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle
>   NSBundle"

The error happens even if I try and use the storyboard that was not imported, the one that runs if the above code is missing. So I am assuming that the error lies in the name of the storyboard. In the project navigator, the storyboard is named `"Main.storyboard"` but calling that name does not find it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you look under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources is it there?

Comment: Yes, both of my storyboards are there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `.storyboard` extension from the name you specify.

From the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName%3abundle%3a):

> ```
> storyboardWithName:bundle:
> ```
>
> Creates and returns a storyboard object for the specified storyboard resource file.
>
> ```
> + (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name
>                               bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *name* The name of the storyboard resource file **without the filename extension**. This method raises an exception if this parameter is `nil`.

Comment: That is so odd, this is one of the first solutions I tried and it did not work, but now it is working. Thanks for the help. I'll mark this as the answer.